# How to recover my password in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, passwords

I have a serious problem with my Mac - I don't need to enter my password to login but when I need to edit a file using the vi editor I have to enter the password. I don't remember the password - is it possible to recover it?

Answer (score 2):

From the Mac Help, when searching for "forgot password":

> **If you forget your administrator password**
>
> If you don’t remember your administrator password, you can reset it using the Mac OS X installation disc.
>
> To reset the administrator password using the Mac OS X installation disc:
>
> - Insert the Mac OS X installation disc into your computer’s optical drive (or an optical drive connected to your computer), and then double-click the Install Mac OS X icon.
> - In the Installer, click Utilities, and then click Restart.
> - When the Language Chooser appears, select your language, and then click the Continue button (looks like an arrow).
> - In the Installer, choose Utilities > Reset Password.
> - Follow the onscreen instructions to change the password.

Comment: So in brief:  The functionality you need is available when you boot your Mac on the installation media.